# Cut Tree in Prolog from some depth

Tags: prolog, binary-tree, depth

```
first(M,N):-
     N>0,M=..[H|T],((T==[],write(H));(T\=[],write(H),Q is N-1,second(T,Q))).
second(M,N):-
     N>0,M=[H|T],first(H,N),((T==[]);(T\=[],second(T,N))).
second(_,0):-!.
```

I want to cut tree form some depth.I write some program which give me this result.

```
?- first(s(f(b(m,k),a),t(a,g)),4).
sfbmkatag
True
```

But I want to get this.

```
?- first(s(f(b(m,k),a),t(a,g)),2,X). 
X = s(f,t) 
True

?- first(s(f(b(m,k),a),t(a,g)),3,X). 
X = s(f(b,a),t(a,g)) 
True
```

Please someone help me to solove it.

Comment: What you have is nowhere close the expected output. First you need to add the output parameter `X` and get rid of all the `write/1`.

Comment: You might want to look at this question ([Trim the tree at the specified depth in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50871893/trim-the-tree-at-the-specified-depth-in-prolog)) that has a "getting started" answer which may help you.